# Snowflake - May not be nested inside another window function

Tags: window, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT  BEST_CAV_BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME, SCMS_NAME
, SUM(TOTAL_ACV - MULTI_YEAR_COMPONENT_OF_ACV) OVER (PARTITION BY BEST_CAV_BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME, QUARTER_WITH_YEAR) AS Bookings_Net 
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Bookings_Net DESC)
FROM SBG_DB.SBG_SBGIOPS_BV.BV_SECURITY_SUBSCRIPTION_TOP_CUSTOMERS_FOR_ACV
where EDITION IS NOT NULL  
AND BEST_CAV_BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME IS NOT NULL
AND (NEW_ACV <> 0 OR RENEW_acv <> 0 AND total_acv <> 0)
AND QUARTER_WITH_YEAR IN ('20213')
ORDER BY Bookings_Net DESC
```

For the above query I am getting the below error

"May not be nested inside another window function" - Compilation error

Comment: You've got two window functions when it appears you could have just one. Just use the ROW_NUMBER() from the first window function's partition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select 
* 
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Bookings_Net DESC)
from 
(
SELECT  
      BEST_CAV_BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME
    , SCMS_NAME
    , SUM(TOTAL_ACV - MULTI_YEAR_COMPONENT_OF_ACV) OVER (PARTITION BY BEST_CAV_BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME, QUARTER_WITH_YEAR) AS Bookings_Net 
FROM 
    SBG_DB.SBG_SBGIOPS_BV.BV_SECURITY_SUBSCRIPTION_TOP_CUSTOMERS_FOR_ACV
where 
     EDITION IS NOT NULL  
 AND BEST_CAV_BUSINESS_UNIT_NAME IS NOT NULL
 AND (NEW_ACV <> 0 OR RENEW_acv <> 0 AND total_acv <> 0)
 AND QUARTER_WITH_YEAR IN ('20213') ) 
ORDER BY Bookings_Net DESC
```

[image]